# DNS records for a web page

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a domain xyz.com, on which an e-mail box is hanging now (user@xyz.com).

I want to configure it so that

a) when the user enters xyz.com in the browser, the user is directed to a home page, which is located in on a web hosting with IP addresses A and B and
b) the e-mail address is still working.

Question: What DNS records should I add to implement this?

Thanks in advance

Dmitri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email is delivered using the MX record (or records) for the domain. You need to make sure that the MX record will still resolve to the current host. Check the current MX records do not reference xyz.com directly. If they do, create a new A record (e.g. mail.xyz.com) and set the MX record to the new A record.

Now change your existing xyz.com domain to the new IP address of the web site. I'd suggest adding a www.xyz.com CNAME record to xyz.com.

So you should end up with:

```
xyz.com       MX  0 mail.xyz.com
mail.xyz.com  A     <mail server IP address>
xyz.com       A     <hosting IP address>
www.xyz.com   CNAME xyz.com
```